# Can I mock SqlConnection.BeginTransaction c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have to work with some legacy code that I cannot change. I have to write classes of that implement an interface called "ITask" that has a method called "RunTask" that accepts a concrete type called Schedule e.g;

```
 public void RunTask(Schedule thisSchedule)
 {
     //I have to do stuff with thisSchedule, no I can't fix that name...
 }
```

Although the legacy code does not use unit testing I would dearly like to use it for my work but the problem is "thisSchedule". I have made a fake version of Schedule that derives from it and am attempting to take control over how all the methods within it function (it is probably a fool's errand). So far I have been successful by exploiting the alarming number of virtual methods or by using reflection but I have hit my first show-stopper

I cannot connect to the real database and I have a method that is often called;

```
public void BeginTransaction()
{
    MyTransaction = MyConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
}

internal SqlConnection MyConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
```

This throws an exception because the connection is closed, Ideally I would like to be able to set a flag stating that the method was called and then just swallow the exception but I would be happy to simply ignore the exception.

Anything, no matter how nasty that will allow me to get past this method call would be an acceptable answer. It's that or defeat.

I am not allowed to use paid-for services like typeMock or shims in visual studio enterprise.

EDIT

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace PredictionServicesTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void BeginTransaction_WhenCalled_SetsTransactionStartedToTrue()
        {
            Schedule schedule = new FakeSchedule();

            schedule.BeginTransaction(); //It would be enough to simply get past this line to the Assert

            Assert.IsTrue(((FakeSchedule)schedule).TransactionStarted); //This would be nice, but isn't vital
        }

        class Schedule
        {
            private SqlTransaction MyTransaction;
            internal SqlConnection MyConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            public void BeginTransaction()
            {
                MyTransaction = MyConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
            }
        }

        class FakeSchedule : Schedule
        {
            public bool TransactionStarted { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Please remember I cannot change the Schedule class, if only things could be that simple!

The ITask interface;

```
    interface ITask
    {
        void RunTask(Schedule thisSchedule);
    }
```

Comment: You can shim/fake it with Microsoft Fakes depending on your Visual Studio version. In 2015/2017 it is included with Enterprise edition. In 2013 its included with Premium and Ultimate edition.

Comment: You can use Moq which is free. Also look into using interfaces. Will make unit testing this type of stuff easier. In the case of transaction, perhaps you can pass in IDbTransaction.

Comment: "not allowed to use paid-for services like typeMock or shims" is this a technical limitation?

Comment: Moq for the win. AFAICT it is a magic bullet, when it comes to mocking in .Net.

Comment: The fact that you are "newing" up the SQL connection within the class makes it difficult to invert the control and make it more testable. Another option would be to connect to a **dummy database** and use that connection. the dummy database would have just enough to allow the test to be exercised.

Comment: provide more details in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. May be then a solution/workaround could be found but if code under test cannot be refactored then that makes things more difficult.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras - I agree it would be much easier to use interfaces or abstract classes, but I am not allowed to change the signature of the method. I am therefore limited to inheriting from Schedule if I want to try to fake it.

Comment: @A.Chiesa I can use Moq and other free mocking frameworks to mock concrete classes, but they only work on virtual methods, the method in my example is not virtual.

Comment: @mark_h Then you may be kind of stuck at this point. Nkosi has a good suggestion if you can do it.

Comment: @mxmissile I cannot use paid-for services for several reasons, my employer won't pay for it and even if I bought it myself or used a free trial I don't have admin rights to install. The reasons don't really matter though, for the purposes of this question they would not be considered an "answer"

Comment: @mark_h - so what version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Nkosi, I have tried to provide a minimal complete verifiable example, I said I could not connect to the real database because I did not want to read/write from/to it. However I and everyone else in my team does have access to a local copy of the DB that would not expose me to much risk of harm. Connecting to the DB would be just about acceptable if it meant that I could get past this method call and then shut down the connection and change the connection string to prevent further accidental calls to a real DB. It  would certainly be classed as a "nasty" solution!

Comment: @Igor VS2015 Professional edition, I don't have access to the Shim feature of the Enterprise edition sadly

Comment: @mark_h - maybe [prig](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sug.Prig-OpenSourceAlternativetoMicrosoftFakes) is an acceptable alternative. This should be able to do what MS Fakes does.

Comment: @Igor - That looks really promising thanks!

Comment: @Nkosi, thank you for pointing out the error(s) in my unit test, I have edited my question so that the call to BeginTransaction is made against a Schedule type and then cast it back to FakeSchedule for the assert.

Comment: @mark_h now by change do you mean that you don't have access to the source and that you cannot change the structure of the code. making the method in question virtual will allow for it to be overridden with most common mocking frameworks. I am gettign the impression that we are focusing on the wrong things here. Are you in control of `ITask` interface? At this point the question is now unclear.

Comment: @mark_h that legacy code should be treated as 3rd part code you have no control over. encapsulate that code behind an abstraction you do control and use that. Not much else can be done given the current restrictions.

Comment: @Nkosi, my job is to make classes that implement the interface ITask (which I have now included in the question). My employer will not let me change the signature of this interface nor edit the Schedule class. If I can pass a fake version of Schedule I will be able to unit test but Schedule only has some virtual methods, the one listed in my example is one such method that doesn't. I have tackled similar methods before e.g. by using reflection to set the backing fields on non-virtual properties but this one has me beat. I am coming to the conclusion that your previous comment is the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could get was to create an interface named IFake that I would apply to FakeSchedule;

```
public interface IFake
{
    Action GetFakeAction(Action action);
}

public class FakeSchedule : Schedule, IFake
{
    public bool TransactionStarted { get; set; }

    public Action GetFakeAction(Action action)
    {
        return () => TransactionStarted = true;
    }
}
```

I then created the following extension method;

```
    public static void Testable<T>(this T obj, Action action)
    {
        if(obj is IFake)
        {
            action = ((IFake)obj).GetFakeAction(action);
        }
        action();
    }
```

This allowed me to call the BeginTransaction method like this;

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void BeginTransaction_WhenCalled_SetsTransactionStartedToTrue()
    {
        Schedule schedule = new FakeSchedule();
        var connection = new SqlConnection();

        schedule.Testable(schedule.BeginTransaction);

        Assert.IsTrue(((FakeSchedule)schedule).TransactionStarted); 
    }
```

Obviously this solution is far from ideal but it works, if I'm running a unit test then the call to begin transaction is diverted away from the real implementation.

The version I implement will need some work (my implementation of GetFakeAction is too dumb) but it's the closest I think I am going to get, the only other solution I can see would be to either use [Prig](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sug.Prig-OpenSourceAlternativetoMicrosoftFakes) or to follow [NKosi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355002/1446086) and connect to a dummy database.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are "newing" up the SQL connection within the class makes it difficult to invert the control and make it more unit test friendly.

Another option would be to connect to a dummy database and use that connection. The dummy database would have just enough to allow the test to be exercised as an integration test.

That legacy code should be treated as 3rd party code you have no control over. And you should not waste time testing 3rd part code you have no control over. Common practice is to encapsulate 3rd party code behind an abstraction you do control and use that. The legacy code demonstrates [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) that is being cashed in with the current difficulties that it is presenting because of poor design.

Not much else can be done given the current restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to unit testing, any external dependency needs to be isolated. Different frameworks have different ways of isolating external dependencies, as well as limitations of what they can isolate.

Many frameworks allow you to create a mock of an interface, so that you can provide an implementation for members in a controlled state. A lot of these frameworks also work well with abstract members of abstract classes. However, very few frameworks support the ability to provide an implementation on a concrete class (non-abstract member). The only two I'm aware which are available are:

- [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page)
- [Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)

---

Both of these frameworks utilize the .NET Profiler API to intercept member calls to replace them with code you provide. I'm not too familiar with TypeMock Isolator, but I am very familiar with Microsoft Fakes. The Microsoft Fakes framework supports generating an assembly (i.e. System.Fakes.dll) which contains classes that allow you to provide your own implementation on members. It supports creating Stubs against interfaces and abstract classes (equivalent to "mocks"), and Shims against concrete and static classes.

If you choose to use Microsoft Fakes, you'll first need to generate a fake assembly against System.Data.dll, which is where `SqlConnection` resides. This will generate the `ShimSqlConnection` class, and this class will contain members which allow you to provide alternative implementations of the `SqlConnection` class' members. Here is an example of how that could be done:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        // Arrange
        SqlConnection.AllInstances.BeginTransactionIsolationLevel =
            (instance, iso) => { ... };

        // Act

        // Assert
    }
}
```

Of course, whether it is a mock, shim, stub, whatever... you should provide alternative implementation which simulates the behavior you want. Since you are replacing the [`SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx) member, you must still follow it's contract and expected behavior; you should not return a value or throw an exception that the actual implementation would not do. At my company, we utilize Microsoft Fakes to simulate scenarios such as:

- *What happens if a `Stream` is closed when we read from it?*
- *What happens if the user/pass is wrong for an `HttpWebRequest`?*
- *What happens if we want our database to return two rows (i.e. control the `SqlDataReader.Read()` member)?*

In all of these scenarios, our goal was to isolate the implemented behavior of these members and replace them with implementations which could realistically occur in a controlled experiment.

---

**Update:**

I just noticed that the original poster stated *"I am not allowed to use paid-for services like typeMock or shims in visual studio enterprise."*. If that is a restriction, then you will have to find another tool that I am unaware of that utilizes the .NET Profiler API or utilize the framework yourself. [`Profiling (Unmanaged API Reference)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As you correctly point out in your update, I cannot access paid-for services so as useful as the information is, it doesn't answer the original question however [prig](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sug.Prig-OpenSourceAlternativetoMicrosoftFakes) has been suggested as a free alternative that I have yet to try out

Comment: @mark_h: Interesting. I've never heard of prig, but it's good to know that a third framework exists, and that this one is completely free/open-source.

Comment: @myermian, please write your opinion about [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539990).